# Strange Error Log which caused Apache Server to restart

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

There are some error logs 
[Wed May 11 13:27:36 2016] [error] [client 157.55.39.65] (36)File name too long: access to

> /\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa0\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9e\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x82\xc2\xa0\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xbe\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa6\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa0\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9e\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa6\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x82\xc2\xa6\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa6\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa0\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9e\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa6\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa6\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa6il&n_id=426&Itemid=10
>   failed (filesystem path
>   '/home/mntp/public_html/\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa0\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9e\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x82\xc2\xa0\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xbe\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa6\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa0\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9e\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa6\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x82\xc2\xa6\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa6\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa0\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9e\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa6\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa0\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa2\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xa6\xc3\x82\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x86\xe2\x80\x99\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9a\xc2\xac\xc3\x85\xc2\xa1\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xa1\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa6il&n_id=426&Itemid=10')

As per the host this has lead to

> [Wed May 11 14:04:58 2016] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing
>   restart

However - thetre is no such file in public_html folder, whose name is that too long and the server failed to open/generate it.

Can anyone help on it pls

**Update**
While checking recent previous logs - the errors are shown for some ip address
157.55.39.152
157.55.39.65
157.55.39.70
157.55.39.224
40.77.167.62
157.55.39.13
157.55.39.21
207.46.13.106

Shocking is that all ip belongs to bingbot. Shall i block bing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this particular requesting client resolves to search.msn.com, the  Request is of a nature that is often malicious, where the "normal" text is encoded to attempt to evade filtering, pass executable code, etc. If you monitor your web logs, you will often see this type of activity.

You can mitigate against this by dialing down your [`LimitRequestLine` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline), and similar "Limit" directives to keep these "large" dumps out of your server.

Although, as the documentation suggests, you will likely have to adjust to your situtation, I have without problem used:

```
LimitRequestLine 512
LimitRequestFields 100
LimitRequestFieldSize 1024
LimitRequestBody 102400
```

Indeed, this error message looks like a limit (either in config or default) was likely hit. This is what you want to have happen if someone (or, more likely, some bot) attempts to make a Request that exceeds the bounds of any legitimate Request line, etc. on your server.

As to there being "no such file in public_html folder," your web logs will show that MOST of your traffic may be "probing" Requests, where there is in fact no corresponding target on your server.

Finally, as to the restart: it happened long after the "bad" request. I see no evidence that the two are related, and it may have been something as simple as a log rotation or even a manual restart that simply followed the earlier request.

As to "picking" the settings that are right for you, you will (for each directive) have to follow the advice in the documentation. In the case of the `LimitRequestLine` directive, for example, the documentation notes that:

> The LimitRequestLine directive allows the server administrator to set the limit on the allowed size of a client's HTTP request-line. Since the request-line consists of the HTTP method, URI, and protocol version, the LimitRequestLine directive places a restriction on the length of a request-URI allowed for a request on the server. A server needs this value to be large enough to hold any of its resource names, including any information that might be passed in the query part of a GET request.

For additional guidance on these, and MANY, other "security" steps, you might check out the [Center for Internet Security (CIS) Security Benchmarks program](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/), which will let you download *free* guidance for hardening many web servers and operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. just one more thing as the log error shows time of 13:27:36, while the apache restarted at 14:04:58.  can the error message can take that long to hit the limit to restart apache. Also - how to ensure that a legtimate request is not limited through above

Comment: @Gag See added explanation in answer

Comment: Thanks - as you referred that as there is no such file in public_html folder with no corresponding target on server, does that mean the error is harmless and in no way can impact the server and no way related to restarting apache as mentioned. thanks

Comment: Probably, but you need to take actions to protect your server from these "attacks." I am going to edit the answer again with a resource to help with this.

Comment: Hi Colt - thanks, i have just added some ip address, shocking is that all these belongs tp bingbot and there been many such errors due to same. shall i block bingbot

Comment: @Gag  - Definitely **DO NOT block bingbot IF you want to be indexed on the Bing search engine!** I tried for about an hour to decode the hex, and could only get to a bunch of jibberish. There is probably some error going on in their system (like they "think" that is a link on your page). If they get 403, 404, etc. return codes they will stop crawling the "bad" link. If you are getting all other traffic appropriately, it would not appear to be an error in your config. You _should_, however, take some time to explore hardening. _We all should._

Comment: Hi -- thanks Colt for the time spent. Yes - all other traffic is usual. Thus - its a harmless issue, though thats right server security is important